# Deleting Rows from Teradata Table Not Decreasing Table Size

Tags: teradata

It is a very basic operation which I am doing but still there is a weird situation. I am trying to delete records from a Teradata table, rows are successfully deleted, even number of rows of overall table decreases but table size is increasing. I have verified at my end, there is no other job inserting data into that. Still whenever I delete data its size increased every time.

Comment: So upon investigation, the table is block level compressed. I have checked using "HELP STATS VALUES ON DATABASENAME.TABLENAME"

can anyone help to delete data from this table?

Comment: WIth BLC it's possible but unusual for deleting rows to result in less compression / more physical space. There are also some types of tables where DELETE does not physically remove rows (Column-Partitioned tables or Load Isolated tables).

Comment: Is this a Temporal Table or a Columnar Table?

Comment: no it is not a temporary or columnar table. We have defined PIs on that table as well.
@dnoeth

Comment: If DELETE does not physically remove rows then the size of the table should remain the same. However, in my case whenever I delete the data its size increased, that is why I think it is due to the BLC. @Fred

Comment: Another possibility is that Online Archive Logging was mistakenly left active for that table. `SELECT * FROM DBC.ArchiveLoggingObjsV WHERE DatabaseName='DatabaseName' and TVMName='TableName';` to check. If there is a row then `LOGGING ONLINE ARCHIVE OFF FOR DatabaseName.TableName;` to clear.

Comment: @Fred yes this could be possible reason, but DBC.ArchiveLoggingObjsTbl is empty. As a way around, I created a separate table with records I need to keep and then drop the original table and renamed my newly created table to original one.